# Limit with log differentiation-help me understand why

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

Evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{x}}$$

This is what I have-I know the answer is wrong, but I don't know why:

$$y=(1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{x}}$$

$$\ln{y}=2x^{-1}\ln{(1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2})})}$$

Use taylor expansion...

$$\ln{y}=2x^{-1}(\arctan{(\frac{x}{2})}-\frac{(\arctan{(\frac{x}{2})})^{2}}{2}+ H.O.T.)$$

Taylor expand again...

$$\ln{y}=2x^{-1}((x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+H.O.T.) - \frac{(x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+H.O.T.)^{2}}{2} +H.O.T.)$$

Evaluate first few terms to identify pattern, all terms in Big O (x)

$$\ln{y}=2 + O{(x)}$$

exponentiate

$$y=e^{2 + O(x)}$$

Thus
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{x}}= y=e^{2}$$

The answer- I know by way of wolfram, is simply e, but I don't understand why my solution is wrong.

Comment: Simple mistake: You used the Taylor expansion of $\arctan x$, but you have $\arctan \frac{x}{2}$. That's where the factor of $2$ comes from.

Comment: Much obliged. It appears that my attention to detail needs improvement. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Check the Taylor series for the inverse of tangent.
$$
\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\qquad;\qquad\text{for}\ |x|\le1.
$$
In our case
$$
\arctan \frac x2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left(\frac x2\right)^{2n+1}\qquad;\qquad\text{for}\ |x|\le1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is:

$$\arctan\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac x2+O(x^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit is
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\ln{(1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2})})}}{x}\right)=\\
\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{4}{\left({4+x^2}\right)(1+\arctan{(\frac{x}{2})})}\right)=\\
\exp\left(\dfrac{4}{\left({4}\right)(1)}\right)=e$$

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change the representation of the limit. Make the the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2\cdot \ln\left(1+\arctan\dfrac x2\right)}x\right)$$

since the limit = $0/0$, indeterminate form, use L'hopital's Rule and evaluate it further.